# Retrieve Value from SQLITE Table and use to query another table

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I am retrieving a value from a SQLITE table and then using this value to retrieve data from another table using a SELECT FROM WHERE statement. I cannot use the retrieved value to query the other table even though the values appear to match when I retrieve this value independently from the table I am querying. I get Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. I am passing the value I believe correctly from what I've read in the docs, but there is obviously something wrong.

**Edit:** The ulitmate goal is to select the Name and EndTime then insert the EndTime value in another table in the same db if a column value = Name in that table. Added Update code below that gives an idea of what I'm attempting to accomplish.

When I print nameItem it appears this is a unicode string, (u'Something') is how it appears. I don't know if this is an encoding issue, but I have used similar queries before and not run into this issue.

I have tried to use the text I am searching for directly in the SELECT query and this works, but when passing it as a variable I still get unsupported type.

```
c.execute('SELECT Name FROM Expected WHERE Timing = 1')
timeList = c.fetchall()
for i in range(len(timeList)):
    nameItem = timeList[i]
    c.execute('SELECT "EndTime" FROM Expected WHERE "Name" = ?', (nameItem,))
    end = c.fetchone()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(otherDb)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('UPDATE Individuals SET Ending = end WHERE NAME = NameItem')
```

I expect this to retrieve a time associated with the current value of nameItem.

Comment: Hi. I suppose that's because you get a tuple in `nameItem = timeList[i]` . Can you add content of the `timeList` variable?

Comment: `[(u'Item1',), (u'Item2',)]` is how the timeList variable appears when printed to the console

Comment: There's almost never a good reason to iterate over range(len(something)); always iterate over something directly.

Answer (score 0):

The first fix to try is to use string instead of tuple (note `timeList` is list of tuples):

```
nameItem = timeList[i][0]
```

But better is to not use len, something like:

```
c.execute('SELECT Name FROM Expected WHERE Timing = 1')
timeList = c.fetchall()
for elem in timeList:
    nameItem = elem[0]
    c.execute('SELECT "EndTime" FROM Expected WHERE "Name" = ?', (nameItem,))
    end = c.fetchone()
```

And even better is to fetch EndTime in the first query (looks acceptable in given context):

```
c.execute('SELECT Name, EndTime FROM Expected WHERE Timing = 1')
timeList = c.fetchall()
for elem in timeList:
    name = elem[0]
    end_time = elem[1]
```